# Indexing specific items in a list

Tags: indexing, slice

How can I index the following items using code in this random data set:

```
    Move number (0,1,2,3 etc) in all lines
```

In the first line - the value '3'
In the first line - the starting direction (character string) 'South east'

```
 In the remaining lines -the movement instruction (character string)' Move & turn left' etc.


    [[0, 3, 'South east'],
    [1, 'Move & turn left'],
    [2, 'Move & turn right'],
    [3, 'Move & turn left'],
    [4, 'Move forward'],
    [5, 'Move & turn right'],
    [6, 'Move & turn right'],
    [7, 'Move & turn right'],
    [8, 'Move & turn right'],
    [9, 'Move & turn left']]
```

I have tried using print statements to identify list items

```
    print(function_name [0][2]) to return what is item is being identified etc.
```

Unsure if slicing is needed to return what I am after specifically.